# Empty window popping up after resume from suspend

Tags: wifi, networking, suspend

After resuming from sleep (i.e. opening the laptop lid) an otherwise empty window is on top with title "..." and a spinner as content.

[image]

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: This window checks internet connectivity / displays a login window for a public wifi. If it disappears , it is that network connectivity is restored without any user interaction.

Comment: That is odd. The laptop is connected to my own private wifi network. And is not disappearing either, I have to close it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug.
It just checks if there is internet connection.

After a while it should print a text 'You are now connected to the internet blah blah blah...'. :)

It's just an information for you.

Comment: The thing is, it stays open indefinitely, spinning and all.

Comment: Can you close it with an X?

Comment: Yes it can be closed by clicking the close button.

Comment: So close it. I don't know how it works, but on my computer it pop up after a 10-20 minutes of using computer.

Comment: Don't you agree that it should not pop up on the first place?

Comment: I agree, but It's like with a cool girlfriend - she may not be the most beautiful without make up, but you love her for a bunch of other things. :) I think that it doesn't affect my productivity so much that I should fight with it.

Comment: Point taken ;-). I guess we are going to have to live with it for now.